# Checkbox formula two picklist fields

Tags: formula, formula-field, picklist

I am working on a formula checkbox field that should flag true if 2 picklist fields (each on different objects) are the same:

```
IF( 
    ISPICKVAL(Child_object_picklist, "Child_object_picklist__r.parent_object_picklist__c"), 
    TRUE, 
    FALSE
)
```

The picklist values on these two fields are the same. So, if picklist value A (from child object) is equal to picklist value B (from related parent object), I would like the checkbox to be flagged true.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IF(<condition>, true, false)` can always be reduced to simply `<condition>`

Beyond that, your current attempt is trying to compare the value of "Child_object_picklist" to the literal string `"Child_object_picklist__r.parent_object_picklist__c"`. That is to say, you're not actually comparing the two picklist values together here.

For what you want to do, you should be using `TEXT()`, which can work with picklist fields.

```
TEXT(Child_object_picklist__c) == TEXT(parent__r.parent_object_picklist__c)
```

Also worth noting is that this formula *must* be on the child object to work.
Formulas can get data from parent records (because there's only ever one parent), but can't go from parent to child (because there can be many children).